# is it possible to use regular Django+templates and Django restframework+a javascript framework in the same project?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm just wondering since Jquery is used less and less and instead of classic use with Ajax, if it is possible to let for example React or Vue handle all of the functionality where Javascript would be needed with **DRF** in one hand , and consider all of it as statics.

And in the other hand, keep working with **Django** and regular templates.

i'm just asking about the **possiblity** to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are many tutorials available for using Django, some with Wagtail as a CMS, with DRF as the backend. You can use a single template, and Vue or ReactJS for the front-end.

Here's a workshop video that might help get you started from the folks at Learn Wagtail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUWd3o6z2bk

(I chose Wagtail, because it is a popular Django CMS with DRF API endpoints out-of-the box.)